# What is the most pythonic way to run subprocess save the output in a variable and load it into a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, subprocess

I am finding difficulties to do this

```
# Save the bash process in a python variable
cmd='bedtools intersect -wao -b/path/file_a -a /path/file_b'
p=Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT,close_fds=True)
output=p.stdout.read()

# Import this string that is a tsv
df=StringIO(output)
cnvs=pd.read_csv(df,
                            sep='\t',
                            index_col=False,
                            names=['#CHROM',
                                   'START',
                                   'END',
                                   'CNV_TYPE'
                                    'CNV ID',
                                   'Chromosome_g'.
                                   'Transcript_start_g',
                                   'Transcript_end_g',
                                   'Transcript_stable_ID_g',
                                   'canonical_g',
                                   'Gene stable_ID_g',
                                   'Gene_name_g',
                                   'amount_overlap_g'])
```

I have been trying different approaches found from different tutorials. As it is now I get the error

```
TypeError:initial_value must be a str or None, not bites
```

More than fix the error I want to know if this is the way of doing this.

Originally I was saving the output of the bash command in a file and then loading the file into pandas. I am not only think that this is not the most pathonic way of doing this but also I am working in a HPC and it is very slow to create a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's especially unpythonic, personally. It's more or less what I would do if I had a command that printed a tsv to stdout. To fix the error, note that stdout is a bytes object. So, use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`. (Also, I would use `with Popen(...) as p:`; that *is* a bit more Pythonic)